# How to resolve MSB3277 warning message in Visual Studio while building Test project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using XUnit project to test my .net core 2.2 web API project, but while building the application I got **MSB3277** warning message.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: To any one trying to help: I'm experiencing the same while using NUnit 3.11.0. Warnings started to show up when I upgraded from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference without version to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in your test project file.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Its working fine! However, I fixed this problem by adding following  required packages into my test project `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />` and `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.0" />`